# Navigation menu - background  on hover behave strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a navigation menu for which I have applied pie.js (library that allows you to have css3 on ie6-8 browsers). Works well at first sight but if we will play a little bit with the menu, wrong behavior will raise:(. To receive that strange behavior you must move cursor a little faster left and right over the drop-down menu on IE8. This is a function through I call js library.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.PIE) {
        $('.aahov,ul#menu,ul#menu li ul').each(function(){
            PIE.attach(this);
        });
    }
```

});

Check this example: http://mainpage.ueuo.com

...and don't forget, only on IE8 browsers ...

Thank's.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML and script code to your post please, what is `PIE`? This will make little sense to any future user possibly looking for a similar solution to a similar issue ones link-rot sets in and the linked site is either gone or has changed. If possible add a fiddle as well on jsfiddle.net to allow others to apply changes to test possible soltions.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl you have all code in example, is you save the page as html you 'll have all htlm,css and js files... PIE.js is a js library that allows you to have css3 in ie6-8 browsers, read description.

Comment: Just to re-iterate: `This will make little sense to any future user possibly looking for a similar solution to a similar issue ones link-rot sets in` Basically, ones your link is dead or the site has changed the question makes no sense any more. That is why the relevant css, script and/or html should always be included where appropriate.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl when is possible yes but in this case if I'll put html,css and js here you have to scroll 2 miles down to see all code. Generally I like to read answers regarding my question and not sugestions...

Comment: Try ta call your function on .mouseover instead of document ready...

Answer (score 3):

It might just be IE8 adding some extra padding.

I noticed from your css that you aren't using a css reset which may help to eliminate browser based differences.

You could have a look at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/  or something similar.

Also IE8 doesn't support last-child

> ul#menu li ul li:last-child{      border-bottom:none; }

So this will also affect the look of your menu items.

Also as a side note from a usability point of view it would be good practice to let the user know that the menu link is a drop down. Possibly add a down arrow to the right of the link.

Answer (score 2):

Your scripting looks good to me, it looks like it's something in your styling.  Not really sure what you have there, but you might be able to work it around to use `overflow:hidden`, or at least that might be a place to start.

Comment: and where i must add that overflow:hidden; ?